# Correct use of lazy instantiation

Tags: swift, lazy-initialization

My understanding of lazy instantiation is that it should be used in cases where

- the lazy property may or may not need to be initialized and/or
- the initialization of the property is potentially expensive and/or
- the initialization of the property depends on other parameters that may not be known in advance.

And yet, I come more and more across code like this [pseudo code]:

```
class SomeClass {
    lazy var itemSize: CGSize = { return CGSize(width: 80, height: 80) }()

    ....
    init() {
        [use itemSize for some init work]
    }
}
```

To me, this does not make sense since itemSize will always need to be initialized, is not expensive and does not depend on any unknown property.  Am I missing something ?

Comment: I think its good also because it allows you to set anything in the small lazy block of code as opposed to some people that would have a massive viewDidLoad: full of configuring different aspects of their properties.

Comment: @SeanLintern88 that block of code is not associated with it being lazy. Any property can be instantiated with a block like that. I often use... `let blah: UILabel = {...}()` for setting up properties that the rest of the class needs access to. It can even be used inside of functions to create variables etc... Not just properties.

Comment: Another related insight: `lazy` instance properties may not be immutable. All _type_ properties (`static ...`/`class ...`), however, are `lazy` by default, and you may naturally implement immutable type properties. So there are `lazy` immutable properties, namely immutable type properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you've omitted (or elided into your third bullet point) the most common reason for `lazy` instance properties: they can refer, explicitly or implicitly, to `self`, whereas normal instance properties cannot.

Another point: `lazy` instance properties do not have to be define-and-call anonymous functions, and in the silly example you give, there is no reason whatever for it to be so. This would have done just as well:

```
lazy var itemSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
```

Both `lazy` and define-and-call are useful, and are often useful together, but don't confuse them.

Comment: See my book for some examples: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_lazy_initialization

Answer (score 3):

You are absolutely correct.

In that particular case there is no need for lazy instantiation.

The cases that you stated are also correct.

However, there shouldn't be any huge detrimental effect of using lazy instantiation in this case.

But, if I'd seen it like that I would have changed it to a `let` and remove the `lazy`. (Especially if it isn't being mutated at any point).

Comment: Unfortunately `lazy let` is illegal.

Comment: @matt yes, I didn't say it wasn't illegal? So I would use a `let` and not a `lazy`. Maybe I'll clear that up though.